# Noetherian ring - difficulty in understanding the union of infinite ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I was reading the proof that a commutative unital ring is Noetherian if and only if every ideal of it is finitely generated. It said that given a strictly ascending chain $$I_0\subsetneq I_1\subsetneq\cdots$$, $I = \cup_{n=0}^{\infty} I_n$ is finitely generated and thus there exists a $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $I_k = I$.

I had a hard time understanding the union of infinite ideals. Since the chain is ascending and there are infinite ideals, it seems to me that the union doesn't exist? Like whenever I add an ideal in the chain, the union grows bigger... I can't picture the union of infinite ideals (or sets).

I would like to know how to understand the union of infinite ideals/sets. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by «the union does not exist»?

Comment: Small nitpick: you should say "infinite union of ideals" or "union of infinitely many ideals", not "union of infinite ideals". The meaning of "union of infinite ideals" is "a union of ideals, where each ideal in the union has infinitely many elements", which is not what you mean.

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union)

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a very good question. Let's address the basic concern you have: how do we understand a union of infinitely many sets?

In order to understand a set, we need to know exactly what its elements are. For example, we completely understand the set $\{1,2\}$, because we know exactly how to tell whether or not something is an element of $\{1,2\}$! Given any mathematical object $x$, the statement "$x \in \{1,2\}$" is true if and only if $x = 1$ or $x = 2$.

Now suppose we have two sets $X_1$ and $X_2$. How do we understand the set $X_1 \cup X_2$? We need to have some way to determine whether or not something is an element of $X_1 \cup X_2$, and we do! Given any mathematical object $x$, the statement "$x \in X_1 \cup X_2$" is true if and only if $x \in X_1$ or $x \in X_2$.

We understand a union like $X_1 \cup X_2 \cup \dots \cup X_{17}$ in the same way: given any mathematical object $x$, $x$ is an element of $X_1 \cup X_2 \cup \dots \cup X_{17}$ if and only if $x \in X_1$ or $x \in X_2$ or ... $x \in X_{17}$. This tells us how to determine what the elements of $X_1 \cup X_2 \cup \dots \cup X_{17}$ are, and so it fully describes the union as a set!

---

It's exactly the same story for infinite unions. Let's say we have infinitely many sets $X_0, X_1, X_2, \dots$

We can understand the union $\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty X_n$ because we can tell what its elements are! Given any mathematical object $x$, the statement "$x \in \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty X_n$" is true if and only if $x \in X_n$ for some natural number $n$.

This tells us what the elements of $\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty X_n$ are, and thus gives a full description of the set $\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty X_n$.

---

**Example**

For each natural number $n$, let $X_n = \{0,2,4,\dots,2n\}$. Then $\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty X_n$ is the set of all even natural numbers, because:

1. Every element of the union is an element of some $X_n$, and thus is an even natural number.
2. Every even natural number is an element of some $X_n$, and thus is an element of the union.

---

**Practice**

For each positive integer $n$, let $X_n = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : z^n = 1\}$.

1. Is $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ finite or infinite?
2. Is $i$ an elment of $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty X_n$?
3. Is $\pi$ an elment of $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty X_n$?
4. Prove that, for all $w \in \mathbb{C}$, if $w^2 \in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty X_n$, then $w \in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty X_n$.

If everything above makes sense, please attempt to solve these problems! If you get stuck, there is probably more to unpack :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! Could you help check my answers to these problems? My answers are: 1. infinite 2. yes, $i\in X_4$ 3. no, since $|\pi|\neq 1$

Comment: In my original case, is it that we can take the union of infinitely many ideals because given a strictly ascending chain, we know what the $n-th$ ideal $I_n$ is (the chain is somehow fixed)?

Comment: Those answers are correct!

Comment: I guess that's the right idea: once we pick a particular ascending chain, we have particular sets that we are taking the union of. But this is the only kind of situation you can ever find yourself in -- if you write $\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i$, the symbols $X_i$ must refer to specific sets, or else what you wrote down doesn't even make sense!

Comment: Thank you so much!